# how to map an array of images and use it as inline style in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array of 3 images and I want to use it as a background image.

```
import React from 'react'

import Bin1 from './images/bin1.png'
import Bin2 from './images/bin2.png'
import Bin3 from './images/bin3.png'

const array = ['Bin1', 'Bin2', 'Bin3'];


const style = {
  height: '20rem',
  width: '15rem',
  marginRight: '1.5rem',
  marginBottom: '1.5rem',
  color: 'white',
  padding: '1rem',
  textAlign: 'center',
  fontSize: '1rem',
  lineHeight: 'normal',
  float: 'left',
  backgroundImage : `url(${Bin1})`
}
```

So instead of one URL of image, I want to map all three of them. I am new in React and really wanted to know how to solve this one.

Comment: What do you mean by "map all three of them" exactly? Could you elaborate?

Comment: So this is not working? Could you share your error message?

Comment: When you are rendering the component, map over the array and build the style object inside the map function,for each style object append the relevant element (image).

Comment: @BlackMath use the three images as the background, instead of only one.

Comment: @konekoya actually there are no errors, its just for the 3 bins, only one image sets as the background.

Comment: @SomoKRoceS can you please elaborate more? im newbie and want to understand more. thanks!

Comment: Can you add your full component code please so I'll demonstrate on that?

Comment: @SomoKRoceS please refer to the sandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/github/react-dnd/react-dnd/tree/gh-pages/examples_decorators_js/01-dustbin/multiple-targets?from-embed=&file=/src/index.js

So in the Dustbin.jsx, I want to put a 3 different images as the background image instead of black background

Comment: Look at my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

So for `Dustbin.jsx` you will need to create an object of images with key-value as name of the image and the source. Then, appending `backgroundImage` while passing the style object to the div. Now, when you create a Dustbin component, just pass the name of the image you want to render as a prop (I called it `bgImageName`). Like this:

**Dustbin.jsx**

```
import React from "react";
import { DropTarget } from "react-dnd";

// THIS IS THE IMAGES LIST
const backgroundsList = {
  tree:
    "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/02/17/19/33/tree-4857597_960_720.png",
  avocado:
    "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/05/04/18/55/avocado-5130214_960_720.png",
  snowman:
    "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2019/12/22/01/14/snowman-4711637_960_720.png"
};

const style = {
  height: "12rem",
  width: "12rem",
  marginRight: "1.5rem",
  marginBottom: "1.5rem",
  color: "white",
  padding: "1rem",
  textAlign: "center",
  fontSize: "1rem",
  lineHeight: "normal",
  float: "left",
  backgroundSize: "contain"     // TO FIT DIV
};
export const Dustbin = ({
  accepts,
  isOver,
  canDrop,
  connectDropTarget,
  lastDroppedItem,
  bgImageName
}) => {
  const isActive = isOver && canDrop;
  let backgroundColor = "#222";
  if (isActive) {
    backgroundColor = "darkgreen";
  } else if (canDrop) {
    backgroundColor = "darkkhaki";
  }
  let backgroundImage = `url(${backgroundsList[bgImageName]})`;     // PASS A PROPERTY CALLED bgImageName WITH THE NAME OF THE IMAGE WE WANT.
  return connectDropTarget(
    <div style={{ ...style, backgroundColor, backgroundImage }}>     // APPEND HERE
      {isActive
        ? "Release to drop"
        : `This dustbin accepts: ${accepts.join(", ")}`}

      {lastDroppedItem && (
        <p>Last dropped: {JSON.stringify(lastDroppedItem)}</p>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
export default DropTarget(
  (props) => props.accepts,
  {
    drop(props, monitor) {
      props.onDrop(monitor.getItem());
    }
  },
  (connect, monitor) => ({
    connectDropTarget: connect.dropTarget(),
    isOver: monitor.isOver(),
    canDrop: monitor.canDrop()
  })
)(Dustbin);
```

And in `Container.jsx` add a property of background image to each dustbin object, and pass it to the component. like this:

**Container.jsx**

```
import React, { useState, useCallback } from "react";
import { NativeTypes } from "react-dnd-html5-backend";
import Dustbin from "./Dustbin";
import Box from "./Box";
import { ItemTypes } from "./ItemTypes";
import update from "immutability-helper";
export const Container = () => {

// ADD bgImageName TO EACH DUSTBIN OBJECT
  const [dustbins, setDustbins] = useState([
    { accepts: [ItemTypes.GLASS], lastDroppedItem: null, bgImageName: "tree" },
    {
      accepts: [ItemTypes.FOOD],
      lastDroppedItem: null,
      bgImageName: "avocado"
    },
    {
      accepts: [ItemTypes.PAPER, ItemTypes.GLASS, NativeTypes.URL],
      lastDroppedItem: null,
      bgImageName: "snowman"
    },
    {
      accepts: [ItemTypes.PAPER, NativeTypes.FILE],
      lastDroppedItem: null,
      bgImageName: "tree"
    }
  ]);
  const [boxes] = useState([
    { name: "Bottle", type: ItemTypes.GLASS },
    { name: "Banana", type: ItemTypes.FOOD },
    { name: "Magazine", type: ItemTypes.PAPER }
  ]);
  const [droppedBoxNames, setDroppedBoxNames] = useState([]);
  function isDropped(boxName) {
    return droppedBoxNames.indexOf(boxName) > -1;
  }
  const handleDrop = useCallback(
    (index, item) => {
      const { name } = item;
      setDroppedBoxNames(
        update(droppedBoxNames, name ? { $push: [name] } : { $push: [] })
      );
      setDustbins(
        update(dustbins, {
          [index]: {
            lastDroppedItem: {
              $set: item
            }
          }
        })
      );
    },
    [droppedBoxNames, dustbins]
  );
  return (
    <div>
      <div style={{ overflow: "hidden", clear: "both" }}>
        {dustbins.map(({ accepts, lastDroppedItem, bgImageName }, index) => (
          <Dustbin
            accepts={accepts}
            lastDroppedItem={lastDroppedItem}
            onDrop={(item) => handleDrop(index, item)}
            key={index}
            bgImageName={bgImageName}     // DONT FORGET TO PASS bgImageName PROPERTY TO Dustbin COMPONENT
          />
        ))}
      </div>

      <div style={{ overflow: "hidden", clear: "both" }}>
        {boxes.map(({ name, type }, index) => (
          <Box
            name={name}
            type={type}
            isDropped={isDropped(name)}
            key={index}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

[Codesandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-turing-33z42?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)